# When I maximize the ckeditor window, the ckeditor toolbar is partially hidden under the django cms main toolbar

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I see where the cke-maximize css class is added to the editor whenever the maximize button is clicked. However, I can't seem to find where to add my custom .cke-maximize class. I want to either change the z-index or add a padding-top:50px; to .cke-maximize

I've tried adding it to 
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css
&
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css

I've tried putting it in django_admin_style. I've even tried putting it in `<style>` tags on the main template itself. Nothing seems to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix the toolbar overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the admin part of django-cms, it should be possible to add this to `templates/admin/inc/extrastyle.html` (in your project)

```
<style>
    .cke_maximized {
        top: 47px !important;
        // or z-index: 10000 !important;
        // whichever you would prefer
    }
</style>
```

this would override the values that are set by CKEditor javascript until it's fixed in [djangocms-admin-style](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-admin-style/issues/310)

Comment: So, that worked wonders when I put it under the main app folder, not the project folder itself. Thanks!